# Deserializing complex json file into a POJO - works either as one list element, or doesn't

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize this json into a POJO class, so then I'll be able to manage the objects.
JSON:

```
{
 "something": "x",
 "items": [
  {
   "type": "y",
   "id": "123",
   "otherInfo": {
    "tag": "abc",
    "otherId": [
     {
      "first": "qaz",
      "second": "zaq"
     },
     {
[...]
```

There are more than 10 elements like this one.
I wanted to deserialize it, so i used jsonschema2pojo, created classes like Item and otherInfo with getters, setters and constructors.

Then I created an ObjectMapper in my DAO class:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Item items;
    {
        try {
            items = mapper.readValue(new File("path/file.json"), Item.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Item getAllItems(){
       return items;
    }
```

This way I'm getting an empty output.
While changing Item to Item[], I'm getting "MismatchedInputException", because of the "something" that's above the "items" in my JSON.

When I tried to refer to a POJO class that's one level above the Item, I've got the whole JSON as a single array element with everything inside it. It's obvious, but this shows that ObjectMapper works correctly.

Is there any easy or efficient way to deserialize JSON like that one?

Comment: Why note create one more parent class with an attribute "Something" AND a list of Items, then try to deserialize that parent object?

Comment: Thank You for your reply. Maybe it is an option. Could You provide more information about deserializing parent object? I don't think I fully understand what You mean.
Btw. is there no way to 'skip' "something" and just deserialize all the Items?

Edit: Actually, it's not even working with "something" completely removed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a parent object that contains an ArrayList to represent the Item array.

For example:

```
public class MyParentObject {
    String something;
    ArrayList<Item> items;
    public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
       return items;
    }
    // the rest of your getters/setters
}

// the object mapper line becomes:
MyParentObject parentObject = mapper.readValue(new File("path/file.json"), MyParentObject.class);

ArrayList<Item> items = parentObject.getItems();
```

With JSON deserialization, JSON arrays can be directly mapped to ArrayList.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I tried to implement this solution, and I'm getting "non-static method getItems() cannot be referenced from a static context" pointing to ArrayList<Item> items = parentObject.getItems();

Comment: Did you define the getItems method?

Comment: Yes i did, exactly the way you did in edit. I've added @JsonProperty("items") though.
Edit: Okay, wait. I've messed up. Give me a second, it seems to be working now.

Comment: Thank You :) It's working flawlessly now. 
If I may - I have another question: what should I do now, if for example i would like to print only these items, that have a otherId/first equal to "xyz"? 
Should I do something like "parentObject.getItems().get() [...]"?

Comment: No problem.  For your second question, are you looking to know how to iterate through an array list and only print out content that is matching certain criteria?  This sounds to be off topic from this post. You might want do a search or post another question separately.

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't be asking this here.
Thanks again :)